# Not able to encode and decode Url in php

Tags: php

I have created a form and passing dynamic information to the next page through URL.

**edit_user.php**

```
<form class="w3-container " action='edit_action.php?edit_id=<?php echo $edit_id ?>' method='post' name="form"  id="form-e" role="form">
```

URL view: **http://localhost/gst_work/bank/edit_user.php?edit_id=64**

I'm trying to encode Url by urlencode() function to secure data

**below code**

```
<form class="w3-container " action='urlencode(edit_action.php?edit_id=<?php echo $edit_id); ?>' method='post' name="form"  id="form-e" role="form">
```

this return semicolon error every time.

i also want to get this url value in next page i.e. **edit_action.php** page. how this can be achieved with decodeurl() function, right now i'm directly using $_GET['edit_id'] method.

**And what can be different ways for handling and securing URL data in php apart from encodeurl or session ?**

Comment: i see you are trying to seucre your url. Since your id is always going to be an integer. You can enforce the check by `is_numeric`. Also make sure you are using prepared statements. THis would protect against SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. This is the correct syntax

```
<form class="w3-container " action='edit_action.php?edit_id=<?= urlencode($edit_id); ?>' method='post' name="form"  id="form-e" role="form">
```

`urlencode` is a PHP function and should be within the PHP tags.

To access the `edit_id` parameter in `edit_action.php`, use a filtering function like `filter_input()` and do avoid accessing superglobal arrays like `$_GET` and `$_POST` directly.

In your case, `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'edit_id');` since you have the form method set as post.

Comment: What is the result you are getting? Is it `edit_action.php` or `edit_user.php` that should handles the form submitted?

Answer (score 0):

why are you encoding whole url , you just need to encode value which you are passing

```
 <form class="w3-container " action='edit_action.php?edit_id=<?php echo urlencode($edit_id); ?>' method='post' name="form"  id="form-e" role="form">
```